# saveAndFlush() not saving to mock repo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write tests for an API, just new to Spring and Mockito. When i saveAndFlush it doesn't seem to hit the repo. This test passes when it should fail as there should be 1 account in the list. Any idea what i am missing here?

```
public class AccountTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController underTest;
    @Mock
    private AccountRepository repo;
    private Account account = new Account();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       account.setAccountNumber((long) 6666);
        account.setName("Steph");
        repo.saveAndFlush(account);
    }

      @Test
      void list(){
        List<Account> mockList = repo.findAll();
        when(underTest.list()).thenReturn(mockList);
        assert mockList != null;
        assertEquals(0, mockList.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no repository in this case: the Mock is an object pretending to be the real repository but without providing any functionality.
Mockito guarantees that the mock is called (as if it was the real repository) but all methods do nothing (functions returns null or empty lists, every void method does nothing).

In your example findAll() correctly returns an empty list.

The idea is to configure your mock to simulate some behaviour

```
# return a given object when the findById() method (any param) is called
when(repo.findById(isA(Long.class))).thenReturn(new Account());
```

and to verify it behaves as expected

```
# verify save() method is called once
verify(repo, times(1)).save(isA(Account.class));
```

In your specific example you could mock findAll() if your test needs a list which is not empty

```
# return a list with one element
List<Account> list = Collections.singletonList(new Account())
when(repo.findAll().thenReturn(list);

// test something (for example the list is processed/manipulated by the controller
```